# Empty output after clicking 'run'

Tags: commaide

I do not see the result after I click the "Run" button

> "C:\Program Files\Edument Central Europe\Comma Community Edition
>   2020.01\bin\runnerw64.exe" C:\rakudo\bin\perl6.bat -Ilib C:\Users\quest\CommaProjects\monkey\monkey.p6
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

sub MAIN() {
    say 'Hello, Monkey';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the old version of the program, then installed the new version, without saving the settings from the previous version. Then File -> Project Structure -> set Project SDK